# What's all that is associated with Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

There are many things, which I'm starting to know just now.

I never knew that there were two sub-domains:

`facebook.stackoverflow.com` & `devdays.stackoverflow.com`.

Also, I didn't know Coderbits uses Stack Overflow's authentication to aggregate points there..

So, what sub-domains, or SO authenticated websites or anything where SO plays a role?

Comment: willannoysotherusers.stackoverflow.com is my personal portal.

Answer (score 3):

`facebook.stackoverflow.com` was a failed experiment, an attempt to provide a facebook developer portal. When coming in through that, we had some facebook branding and the question list was a facebook tagged subset.

`devdays.stackoverflow.com` was a set of conferences organized by Stack Exchange a while ago. These have been discontinued.

Coderbits is not affiliated with Stack Exchange.

Comment: Talk about open-ended ;)

Comment: It is a **very** open ended question.